# Drawing a Bull's eye target using Loops

Tags: java

So I have to create a bulls eye target in java.swing.
At first I tried hard coding each individual circle but the problem was that the circles wouldn't be centered. So I was hoping there was an easier way using loops instead of hardcoding in every single circle. Heres my code when trying to hard code it:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TargetPanel extends JPanel {



public TargetPanel() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,800));
}//end constructor

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    Color blue = new Color(0, 100, 0);
    Color yellow = new Color(100, 0, 0);

    super.paintComponent(g);
    int dimension = 800;
    int partition = 75;


    drawCirlce(g, Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK, dimension);


}//end draw circle

private void drawCirlce(Graphics g, Color blue, Color yellow, int dimension) {

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillOval((getHeight()/2) - (dimension/2), (getWidth()/2)-(dimension/2), dimension, dimension);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawOval((getHeight()/2) - (dimension/2), (getWidth()/2)-(dimension/2), dimension, dimension);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillOval((getHeight()/2) - (dimension/2), (getWidth()/2)-(dimension/2), dimension-25, dimension-25);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawOval((getHeight()/2) - (dimension/2), (getWidth()/2)-(dimension/2), dimension-25, dimension-25);


}//end drawCircle

}//end main
```

As you can see, this created a smaller circle but it does not quite make the Bulls eye target pattern.
Again I think it can be done in an easier way, I'm just not sure how to go about it. And think making a loop would be easier. Perhaps someone can point me into the right direction.

Comment: Don't create colors blue and yellow like that. Just use Color.BLUE and color.YELLOW. Also, your yellow is really red.

Comment: the colors are just place holders for when I complete the target. I'm not so much worried about the colors as I am getting the right pattern for the bulls eye targer

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't resist this: Perhaps your circles don't want to be centered because of the way you have spelled circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use code like `(getHeight()/2) - (dimension/2)` If both height and dimension are odd numbers, you will truncate both of them and the answer will be wrong.

Better to use `(getHeight() - dimension)/2`.

Note that the x,y coordinates of drawOval() are the upper left hand corner of the rectangle that contains the ellipse, not the center.

Also, it is much easier to read and edit later if you don't try to place everything in one line:

```
int x = ...;
int y = ...;
int width = ...;
int height = ...;
g.fillOval(x,y,width,height);
```

Comment: ok that makes sense! thanks! any idea how I would create the pattern using a for loop tho?

Comment: Declare x, y, width, height outside loop, then loop n times, where n is the number of rings to draw. Start at outer ring and fill smaller and smaller circles as you go in.You just recalculate the 4 values each time through the loop and draw the new(smaller)  filled oval.

Comment: how do I center each circle? it seems to not make the pattern